# Database Change Notifications in ASP.NET using SignalR and SqlDependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I'm a serious MVC & SignalR newbie!

I found [this](http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency) tutorial online that shows how to use Database Change notifications and display the data in an MVC app. The issue I'm having is replicating the MVC side of things. I've managed I think to work through the tutorial correctly and spin up the application, however, I'm getting an Undefined connection and the app bombs out.

Does anyone know where I might find the associated source files for this example, or has anyone managed to successfully implement this and can shed some light on the configuration of this from an MVC point of view.

Thanks!

Comment: Signalr is very easy to setup, start from scratch, create a new MVC4 project, install singalr via NUGET, create a test hub class that returns a string of 'hello world'. Create a client in a view that is connected to the test hub, use jQuery/javascript to update your html with the value returned from your test hub and just build from there.

Answer (score 3):

To display real time updates from the SQL Server by using SignalR and SQL Dependency I've done these steps:

Step 1: Enable Service Broker on the database

The following is the query that need to enable the service broker

```
ALTER DATABASE BlogDemos SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ;
```

Step 2: Enable SQL Dependency

```
//Start SqlDependency with application initialization
 SqlDependency.Start(connString);
```

Step 3: Create the hub Class

```
public class MessagesHub : Hub
    {
        private static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();
        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello();
        }

        [HubMethodName("sendMessages")]
        public static void SendMessages()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessagesHub>();
            context.Clients.All.updateMessages();
        }


    }
```

Step 4: Get the Data from the Repository

Create MessagesRepository to get the messages from the database when data is updated.

```
public class MessagesRepository
    {
        readonly string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        public IEnumerable<Messages> GetAllMessages()
        {
            var messages = new List<Messages>();
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [MessageID], [Message], [EmptyMessage], [Date] FROM [dbo].[Messages]", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        messages.Add(item: new Messages { MessageID = (int)reader["MessageID"], Message = (string)reader["Message"], EmptyMessage =  reader["EmptyMessage"] != DBNull.Value ? (string) reader["EmptyMessage"] : "", MessageDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]) });
                    }
                }

            }
            return messages;


        }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                MessagesHub.SendMessages();
            }
        }
    }
```

Step 5: Register SignalR at startup class

```
app.MapSignalR();
```

Step 6: then use the method to show real time at your view

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js"></script>
 <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var notifications = $.connection.messagesHub;

        //debugger;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
            getAllMessages()

        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            alert("connection started")
            getAllMessages();
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });


    function getAllMessages()
    {
        var tbl = $('#messagesTable');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/GetMessages',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
        }).error(function () {

        });
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am trying to implement this. It gives no error but all data displayed as "undefined" and instead of showing few rows it shows so many rows(in may case it should show 7 rows & 2 columns but shows 91 rows & 2 columns). Any idea why it is not displaying actual records here?

Comment: @giparekh use console.log(result); at ajax success() call back and check if the JSON data is in correct format

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your code, it's easier to figure out what the problem is that way.

From what you have mentioned, I can think of only two things.

1) The tutorial you used, it's using SignalR 1.0. If you are using SignalR 2.0, you should not follow the tutorial exactly.
   A few things changed in SignalR 2.0, you can read about it using below link:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20

2) If you are using SignalR 1.0, make sure you include the "jquery" file correctly, and if it's correct, try to change the hub proxy path like below:

```
  <script src="/signalr/Hubs"></script>
```

Hope it helps